# A way to "revert" the icons on the hot network questions?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, icons

I read through the Hot Network Questions list quite often and it's definitely a great feature for me, but I find it getting more and more difficult to use.

Increasingly, different sites are getting their own icons which are usually very abstract. Where previously, the English Language Learners Stack Exchange had a fairly intuitive speech bubble with an "ELL" it now has an abstract ribbony thing instead. Looking at the HNQ list right now I can't see any icons that are particularly intuitive.

Is there a way to use the older letter-based icons for all questions on the HNQ lists instead of the new ones?

Comment: Just to note - when you hover over any icon, the full name of the site will be there in a tooltip.

Comment: You could write a userscript to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is unable to recognize which question is from what site (due to revamped icons).

As Oded has mentioned in the comment, you get the tool-tip with the site name on hover over their icons

> [image]

So, maybe a feature for allowing to revert the icons would be an overkill.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was aware of this. I certainly appreciate the tooltips but obviously it's inconvenient to do this for every icon (then keep a mental inventory of which icon is which.)

Comment: Additionally, some of the site names themselves are obscure at best (Arqade, Ask Different, even Stack Overflow itself).

Comment: @JonG Didn't know there were so many sites who got their icons revamped :) But, revert feature would be harmful for `just-graduated` beta sites.

Comment: Applying the tooltip to the question title, in addition to the site icon, would help in my opinion. What do you think, @Jon?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I do think it would help, but I don't think it recovers the at-a-glance usability that was previously there. Perhaps an additional improvement would be to add a more sensible name in brackets for the sites with clever names too, e.g. Seasoned Advice (Cooking), Mi Yodeya (Judaism), Cross Validated (Statistics or whatever this is supposed to be)

Comment: @Jon I get your point, but adding too much information might become messy/noise for many. Most people don't really mind this, so userscript as someone mentioned in a comment on the question is ideal. Install it, and only you will see whatever you want.

Comment: Mobile Users don't hover. If you click the icon you actually go to the corresponding page, which might need some time (in low connection zones) and is generally not what I personally want.